# How can I use Python's multiprocessing library to return multiple graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've got a function that simulates a system of biochemical equation over time. My supervisor has asked me to start parallelising it, and wants me to start by just running the whole function several times simultaneously. Below is a picture of the graph plotted by one run of the simulation, essentially I want this graph say 5 times as the result from 5 of the same processes being run in parallel.

[image]

This is the code I've got for plotting the graph:

```
for i, label in enumerate(['Enzyme', 'Substrate', 'Enzyme-Substrate complex', 'Product']):
    plt.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

the `tao_all` is an array containing the current time of the system and the `popul_num_all` is another array that contains all the discrete molecule numbers for each species involved in the system. Both are updated after each iteration of a `while` loop.

This is the code I've got so far for the parallelisation part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool() as Pool:   
    result = Pool.apply_async(gillespie_tau_leaping, [propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, epsi])
print(result.get(timeout=1))
```

My system runs and the reactions are simulated and the above graph is plotted, then the program reaches the parallelisation part and runs again but returns the following graph:

[image]

I'm a bit unsure about the order of the two coding snippets, should I run the parallelisation first and then pass the results to the plotting bit?

And why does the graph change like this after the parallelisation?